# Photosphere calculation

Tags: photosphere, photosphereviewer

Suppose I have a Photosphere (5952X2976), suppose I export some rectangle photo (1080X1400) from it at (fov=100, theta=30, phi=0), how can I map the coordinate on the rectangle photo to the Photosphere photo?

Is there any python library could support this calculation?